# Laravel not fills pivot table in API nested call

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm a beginner in Laravel. I try to create API with nested resources, so:
I have 3 tables

```
word(id, value);
word_categories(id, name);
word_category_word(word_category_id, word_id);
```

My relationships are MANY-TO-MANY.

My models are (typical code not included):

**Word.php**

```
    ...
    public function categories() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(WordCategory::class);
    }
    ...
```

**WordCategory.php**

```
    ...
    public function categories() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Word::class);
    }
    ...
```

I also have 2 categories ( id: 1, id:2 ) and I want create words related to specific category, but my pivot table always empty and each word category has all words.

**api.php**

```
    ...
    Route::apiResource('wordCategories', WordCategoryController::class);
    Route::apiResource('wordCategories.words', WordController::class);
    ...
```

**WordCategoryController.php**

```
    ...
    public function store(StoreWordCategoryRequest $request)
    {
        return new WordCategoryResource(WordCategory::create($request->all()));
    }
    ...
```

**WordController.php**

```
    ...
    public function store(StoreWordRequest $request)
    {
        return new WordResource(Word::create($request->all()));
    }
    ...
```

I use this url:

```
POST:
api/v1/wordCategories/1/words/
body:
 {
   "value": "test"
 }
```

I expect that after call api/v1/wordCategories/1/words/ will create word only for provided (1) word category.
What should I do to get logic which I want?

Comment: 1_In WordCategory you should name the relation method to Words not Categories
2_please define relations completely (read the Laravel doc carefully)
3_you can name the pivot table to category_word, this is more make sense.

Comment: @shaho1090, thank you for your advice! I made a mistake when I created my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've named your relation function wrong if you are following laravel convention. 
try this :
**Word.php :**

```
public function word_categories() : 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(WordCategory::class);
    }
```

**WordCategory.php**

```
public function words() : 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Word::class);
    }
```

and in your **WordController:**

```
    ...
    public function store(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $word_category = WordCategory::find($id);
        $word = new Word;
        $word->value = $data['value'];
        $word_category->words()->attach(word);
    }
    ...
```

This will add the word that you passed it's value to the category (value in request body) that you passed the `id` (1) in the api.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made other changes also, but your answer the most helpful.
I used not $id in store() method, I expected full parent object.